# wikipedia AttributeError on direct run

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, wikipedia-api

For the wikipedia module of python (installed through pip)

When I use ipython and do the following:

```
import wikipedia
print wikipedia.summary("Wikipedia")
```

..it works fine. But when I save the same in a file and run it from shell through:

```
python filename.py
```

It shows **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'summary'**

Why this behavior?

PS: I later included the following in 'filename.py', to list this module's scope:

```
print dir(wikipedia)
```

.. this gives:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'wikipedia']
```

while in ipython, dir(wikipedia) gives all names as expected:

```
['API_URL', ..(snip) .. 'PageError', 'RATE_LIMIT', .. (snip) ..  '__name__', 'time', 'timedelta']
```

Why so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

10 to 1 you named your own script `wikipedia.py`.

The line `import wikipedia` then imports *the script itself*, not the package you installed from PyPI. You can see this in the `dir()` output, the imported module has the name `wikipedia` in the namespace; the self-reference.

You can confirm this, or find what other module masked your import, with:

```
import wikipedia
print wikipedia.__file__
```

Rename that file to stop it from masking the library.